# codeigniter image not showing while index.php including in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have created a website using codeigniter. But i stuck with a problem that when i called the link

```
http://example.com/index.php/about
```

the images and other files on my assets folder is not showing (due to invalid file path). But it is working fine when i am calling

```
http://example.com/about
```

My **.htaccess** file contain the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

and my folder structure is

```
application
assets
    css
    images
system
.htaccess
index.php
license.txt
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: How you have given the path to the images?

Comment: echo out your base_url

Comment: but we cant see where are you calling the images give us a peace of code and little more explanation

Comment: I found my reason for the error. I am getting the image path as 'http://example.com/index.php/assets/images/banner.png' while including 'index.php' on main url as 'http://example.com/index.php/about'. There is no image found on the link. Image is found on 'http://example.com/assets/images/banner.png'. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Lastly i found a solution myself. After adding the following code inside head tag of each view page, i solved this issue.

```
<base href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>" />
```